# How does a T-test between Clusters work?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am a very beginner and stuck with a probably very easy task...

I did a k-means clustering and clustered CO2 footprints. I got 5 clusters which I'd like to analyse. There are 1012 inidividuals. 
For this case, I created a Variable called "capital_econ" (where I used a PCA before).

I would like to check if the clusters are significantly different in mean and median relating to capital_econ? How do I do that?

I found the `t.test.cluster` function from the `Package Hmisc`, but I don't get what "group" and "cluster" and so on really mean.

that's what the help button tells me:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(800)
group <- sample(1:2, 800, TRUE)
cluster <- sample(1:40, 800, TRUE)
table(cluster,group)
t.test(y ~ group)   # R only
t.test.cluster(y, cluster, group)
# Note: negate estimates of differences from t.test to
# compare with t.test.cluster
```

Comment: There is insufficient information for people to help you. Add the names of any packages that you are using. In particular, note where the function `t.test.cluster` comes from. Most likely, people will read the help file to figure out what is going on.

Comment: If you need help deciding what the right statistical test is for your hypothesis, then you should ask over at [stats.se]. It all depends on what assumptions you are willing to make and what sort of inference you want to perform. Choosing a test is not a specific programming question.